# Word problem involving rotation

Tags: trigonometry, rotations

If a wheel rotates at 195 degrees every 1.3 seconds. What will the revolutions per minute be?

Comment: Please extend your question by showing what you have tried to solve the problem and clarifying where you get stuck.

Comment: I recommend you doing some Stoichiometry, if you're having trouble with these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 3):

$\require{cancel}$

$$\dfrac{195^{\cancel{\circ}}}{1.3\cancel{\text{ seconds}}} \times \dfrac{60\;\cancel{\text{seconds}}}{\text{minute}}\times\dfrac{1 \text{ revolution}}{360^{\cancel{\circ}}} = \;\dfrac{?\;\text{revolutions}}{\text{minute}}$$

Comment: Very nice approach +1

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- There are 60 seconds in a minute.

  - So how many time segments of $1.3$ seconds in a minute?
  - So how many degrees rotation per minute?
- There are 360 degrees in a circle.

  - So how many revolutions per minute?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$1 \text{ rev.} =360^{\circ}$

$\therefore 195^{\circ}= \text{ ? rev.}$

Also, $1 \text{ min} =60 \text{sec}$

$\therefore 1.3 \text{ sec} = \text{ ? sec}$